# Import columns and textbox from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have some problems with importing from an Excel workbook.

The Excel workbook has the following columns that needs to be imported to Access:

```
| ID2 | Hours | Total |
+-----+-------+-------+
|     |       |       |
```

In addition to the table from Excel, the workbook has **one textbox** (can be "shape" or ActiveX - I just need to be able to add free text as a description (with more than 255 chars).
The textbox shall be copied to the `Description` column in the Access database, which looks like this:

```
| ID   | ID2 | Description | Hours | Total |
+------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+
| (Ny) |   0 |             |     0 |     0 |
```

I have no problems with importing the table from Wxcel with the following code:

```
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                 acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strTables(intWorksheets), _
                  strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                 strWorksheets(intWorksheets) & "$"
```

But this code can only import the table and its contents.

Do you have any suggestions to how I can import the textbox to the same post in the Access table?

The VBA needs to run from Access, because it's a part of a script which imports hundreds of Excel workbooks.

Comment: You cannot import textbox content into MS Access. Place such text within the cell of a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If possible it is preferable to use Excel VBA for each workbook to copy the Description text to a (perhaps hidden) column of the Excel table, and import it to Access along with the other columns.

---

But if it is a "single" textbox how could it fill an entire column of Descriptions? Unless you intend to repeat the description in each row. (Which would be odd.)

---

If the above is not a possibility then you could use `Excel Automation` to open each file and programmatically locate the Description text, and Update the Access table to include this information.

However,

> it's a part of a script which imports hundreds of Excel workbooks.

for this process to be successful with hundreds of workbooks they would each have to follow the same format. That is, to only have one textbox on the sheet, or for the textbox to always have the same identifiable name.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I prefer not to run the VBA in excel, cause I need the file format to preferably be xlsx, and the users shall not be required to trust the file to use it. The purpose is to gather information from several users in a standardized template with one single textbox and some cells from excel. So there will be one description on each row. If its possible to extract the text from the textbox without opening excel, I could import it to a temporary table and then move it to the correct row in the "main table" in access.Cant find a way to extract the info from the textbox..

Comment: With Excel Automation you will still need to temporarily open, then close, the file in order to obtain the text from the textbox. How to read text from a shape or ActiveX control is too broad a question. You could open a new question for this, but show what you have attempted.